# Not finding Theme path when using eval() code

Tags: php, wordpress

All,
I'm using the following code to try and set an include path for my Wordpress page:

```
$themePath = trailingslashit(get_bloginfo('template_url'));
set_include_path($themePath);
include_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
```

This works fine if I don't use it from within an actual Page in Wordpress. I'm using the Exec-PHP plugin to display my PHP. When I put this in that code it doesn't understand the include path and gives me an error that my Zend/Loader file couldn't be found.

The error message I receive is:

**Fatal error**:  Class 'Zend_Loader' not found in **D:\My Documents\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\exec-php\includes\runtime.php(42) : eval()'d code** on line **31**

The Zend loader is in the following path:
http://localhost/vendor_wordpress/wp-content/themes/themename/

Any idea on how to set the include path and use the Exec-PHP to process my PHP code?

Comment: Give the full path to `Zend/Loader.php`. Additionally if you ask questions here you should add the actual error message as well.

Comment: Do `var_dump(get_include_path())` on a page request.

Comment: @hakre I update my question with the error message and paths.

Comment: @Vague The result of that is: string(70) "http://localhost/vendor_wordpress/wp-content/themes/themename/"

Comment: Why would you set an URL as include path, or even try to include a script from an URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using template_url for includes which gives you URL and not absolute path, which should be used for includes.

What you should use instead is

```
$themePath = ABSPATH . 'wp-content/themes/themename';
```

and you should preserve the original include path as well:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $themePath );
```